# SCSS - best way to organize

Tags: css, sass

Im working with SCSS and I want to structure the code proberly..
In LESS it wasnt a problem, but would you say it is okay to structure the code like below..

imagine that button has its own file.

```
@mixin button-basic {
    .button {
        font-size: 14px;
    }
}

@mixin button-max-480 {
    .button {
        color: red;
    }
}


@mixin button-max-767 {
    .button {
        color: green;
    }
}

@mixin button-max-959 {
    .button {
        color: blue;
    }
}

@mixin button-min-960 {
    .button {
        font-size: 34px;
        color: purple;
    }
}


@media print, screen {
    @include button-basic();
}
```

**in my media-query file..** (imagine having multiple includes within each media Query type.)

```
@media (min-width: 960px) {
    @include button-min-960();
}

@media (max-width: 959px) {
    @include button-max-959();
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    @include button-max-767();
}

@media only screen and (max-width:480px) {
    @include button-max-480();
}
```

Comment: I'd say go onto the code review stack exchange for this one mate.

Comment: At a glance I can suggest combining the 2nd, 3rd & 4th mixins into one single mixin, passing a parameter into it. Based on the parameter, using `@if` statements you could change the color. Something like `@mixin button-max($size) {`

Answer (score 1):

You could work with `@mixins` but I would not recommend this approach because this gets really confusing.

I suggest using modifier classes for each variation and use your `media-query` inside your declaration.

```
.button {

    &--red {
        color: red;
    }

    &--green {
        color: green;
    }

    &--blue {
        color: blue;
    }

    @media (min-width: 768px) {
        font-size: 1.125rem;
    }

    @media (min-width: 960px) {
        font-size: 1.25rem;
    }

}
```

This way you have a really clean code base and can split up each component / module into it's own file.

Comment: but then I would have @media for each major class I have.. 
it not just a matter of colour, could also be container size etc.. 

I see your way, im just not sure its the "better" way ?:/

Comment: It depends ... I absolutely get your point and I was there before.
I highly recommend using multiple @media rules. As I mentioned, this way you can split your modules and test each one individually.
Especially on larger code base this is perfect for scalability and maintainability.
Maybe this one will help you with your project: https://sass-guidelin.es/